# Project planning with MS Project 2007

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project-2007

Working time on Saturday is half day at my company. Thus if a task must be done on a day and start on Saturday then it will finish after Monday morning of next week.
Are there any way to make MS Project 2007 schedule start and finish time of task as above?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to modify the "Standard" calendar in MS Project, and set Saturday to be a working day, and the working hours on Saturday to match those used by your company (for example 9am to 1pm). If you then schedule a one day task starting at 9am on Saturday morning, this will finish in the middle of the day on Monday. You can also associate spefici calendars with resources and individual tasks to control how work is scheduled if you need more fine-grained control (for example you can add holidays for individual resources, and so on).